# onStartCommand Call after Destroying an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, background-service

i'm observing a weird scenario here. I have a background android service which is running perfectly. but when I kill the **process or application** from my `RecentApps` my Application calls the `onStartCommand` method again. I don't know where I went wrong. I have searched alot but didn't find any appropriate solution. Could someone please mention what I did wrong? Thanks in Advance

**Activity:**

```
public class OptionSelectionActivity extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener {

Timer time;
Intent serviceIntent;
private Button btn_selectionquiz, btn_alerts, btn_history;
ConnectionManager cm;
boolean isInternetPresent = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Log.e("onCreate", "im Running");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_option_selection);

    cm = new ConnectionManager(getApplicationContext());
    isInternetPresent = cm.isConnected();

    serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class);
//      serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

//  isMyServiceRunning();
    if(!isMyServiceRunning())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no service running, starting service..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is already running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }

    XmlView();
    RegisterListenerOnXml();
}

private void XmlView() {
    btn_selectionquiz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.optionselection_btn_selectquiz);
    btn_alerts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.optionselection_btn_alerts);
    btn_history = (Button) findViewById(R.id.optionselection_btn_history);
}

private void RegisterListenerOnXml() {
    btn_selectionquiz.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_alerts.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_history.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    isInternetPresent = cm.isConnected();
    if(isInternetPresent)
    {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.optionselection_btn_selectquiz:
        // intent calling
        i = new Intent(this, TeacherSelectionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.optionselection_btn_history:
        // intent calling
        i = new Intent(this, QuizHistoryActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.optionselection_btn_alerts:
        // intent calling
        i = new Intent(this, GettingAlerts.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}else
{
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    alert.showAlertDialog(OptionSelectionActivity.this, "Internet Conncetion", "No internet Connection", false);
}
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if(!isMyServiceRunning())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no service running, starting service..",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 //         startService(serviceIntent);
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is already running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        String temp = service.service.getClassName();
        if ("com.smartclasss.alerts.MyService".equals(temp)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

    @Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    Log.e("onSTOP", "im calling...!!!!");
    if(!isMyServiceRunning())
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There is no service running, starting service..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//          startService(serviceIntent);
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service is already running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();

    Log.e("onRestart", "now im calling after onStop");
}

 }
```

**Service:**

```
 public class MyService extends Service{

private SharedPreferences prefs; 
    private String prefName = "userPrefs";
public static String GETTING_ALERTS_URL = "http://"
        + IPAddress.IP_Address.toString()
        + "//MyServices/Alerts/AlertService.svc/alert";
public static String TAG_NAME = "DoitResult";
public static String TAG_ALERT_TITLE = "alertTitle";
static String Serv_Response = "";
static String Serv_GettingQuiz_Response = "";
boolean flag = false;
boolean isServRun = true;
public Timer time;
ArrayList<Alerts> alertsList;
public static final String INTENT_NOTIFY = "com.blundell.tut.service.INTENT_NOTIFY";
// The system notification manager
private NotificationManager mNM;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}




@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    Log.e("Attendence", "Service Created");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    time = new Timer();
    time.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            final String currentDate = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
//              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service Started :"+" "+currentDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            if(flag == false)
            {
                try {
                    savingDateinPref(currentDate);


                    new DoInBackground().execute(currentDate);  
                    flag = true;
                    isServRun = false;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            String val = prefs.getString("TAG_KEY", "defValue");
            if(!currentDate.equals(val))
            {
            flag = false;
            prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE); 
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 

            editor.remove("TAG_KEY");
             //---saves the values--- 
             editor.commit(); 

            }
        }
    },0,5000);
    return START_STICKY;
}

private class DoInBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    String cellphoneDate = "";

    ArrayList<Alerts> alertsList = new ArrayList<Alerts>();
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cellphoneDate = params[0];
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(GETTING_ALERTS_URL + "/"
                + cellphoneDate);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        try {
            Serv_Response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (Serv_Response != null) {
                ////////////////////////////new code for getting list ///////////////////
                JSONObject jsonObj1 = new JSONObject(Serv_Response);
                JSONArray alertName = jsonObj1.getJSONArray(TAG_NAME);

                for (int i = 0; i < alertName.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = alertName.getJSONObject(i);
                    String alert_title = c.getString(TAG_ALERT_TITLE);
                    Alerts alertObject = new Alerts();
                    alertObject.setAlertTitle(alert_title);
                    alertsList.add(alertObject);
                    }

            }
            }  catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "From Database :" + Serv_GettingQuiz_Response,     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //String array[] = new String[size]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < alertsList.size() ; i++ )
        {
        showNotification(alertsList.get(i).getAlertTitle(), "TAP for More Details", i);
        //  savingDate(Serv_GettingQuiz_Response);
        }
    }

}

private void savingDateinPref(String value){

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE); 
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); 

    //---save the values in the EditText view to preferences--- 
     editor.putString("TAG_KEY",value); 
     //---saves the values--- 
     editor.commit(); 
}
```

}

**Logcat:**

```
06-03 12:25:22.844: E/onCreate(29973): im Running
06-03 12:25:23.174: E/Attendence(29973): Service Created
06-03 12:25:30.702: E/onSTOP(29973): im calling...!!!!
06-03 12:25:32.274: E/onCreate(29973): im Running
06-03 12:25:33.655: E/onSTOP(29973): im calling...!!!!
06-03 12:25:34.366: E/onCreate(29973): im Running
06-03 12:25:35.878: E/onSTOP(29973): im calling...!!!!
06-03 12:25:36.869: E/onRestart(29973): now im calling after onStop
06-03 12:25:45.027: E/onSTOP(29973): im calling...!!!!
```

**`06-03 12:25:48.221: E/Attendence(30447): Service Created`**

here in the logcat the last line shows that its call the onstartcommand method again. Why is it so? Even my Activity is not running I meant to say (the service starts in oncreate method on on acticity, but here in the logcat the control goes directly to the onStartCommand when i destroy my App ).

Comment: Read about Start_sticky http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054588/what-is-start-sticky-start-not-sticky-and-start-redeliver-intent-service

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for your response, Well I have read it, But I don't want to stop my service and as well as I don't want a notification as I kill the process. in my case START_NOT_STICKY is useless. and START_STICKY is working fine but it's get me a notification when I kill the process :(

Comment: note: do not keep service running for longer periods.

Comment: so what's the alternate way then? in my logic I want the notification on datechange, whenever the date change my service communicates with web-service n get a data.

Comment: when you start the app start the service and stop the service when your activity destroys. Its upto you to design.

Comment: @MuneebAmjad: I am facing similar problem.. But in my case, this problem is coming in some devices only like I am getting error in Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 but not in Motorola Moto E2.. Have you got any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Your service will be **START_STICKY** so the android framework is restarting it -> **This will give you call to `onStartCommand()`**

I changed my service to **START_NOT_STICKY** so the android framework will not restart my service on its own without any explicit request from out application

To make your service of **START_NOT_STICKY**, just return value `Service.START_NOT_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`

This worked and solved my issue