# When android service is restarted by the OS due to Sticky flag, is intent passed to it?

Tags: android, service, android-service

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

}
```

When a service is started, I pass an intent to startService function. When service is restarted by the OS due to Sticky flag, is that very same intent that I passed to it to start the service be passed to onStartCommand again or will it be null?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intent is only passed again if you request `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`

[What is START_STICKY,START_NOT_STICKY and START_REDELIVER_INTENT Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054588/what-is-start-sticky-start-not-sticky-and-start-redeliver-intent-service)