# android service restarts itself on application killed

Tags: java, android, service

I am developing an applicaton which communicates with my service via receivers.

Service Code

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(LOCATION_UPDATE);
    mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            receiverWorks(intent);
        }
    };
  this.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
  return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Service's Manifest declaration

```
    <service
        android:name="com.test.IService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="IService"
        android:process=":iservice" >
    </service>
```

Problem is that it restarts itself after application (my application which uses this service) is being killed. How can i prevent this ?  Tried to remove android:process but nothing changes.

Waiting for you help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The service restarts itself because you are returning `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand()`

You need to return `start_not_sticky` instead.

For more info, please read this: [START_STICKY and START_NOT_STICKY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But as i know START_STICKY recreates itself if service is stopped. Problem is why my application destroys the service after it is being closed.