# SignalR - notifying a message when the application is in background or even killed

Tags: android, push-notification, signalr

The SignalR with the Java library is a great choice for realtime communication.
Though it is possible to subscribe to hub on the onCreate and to close it.
But what happens when the application is killed ( manually or automatically) or even the activity is dead.
One solution is to use a service - that is basicly same as creating a GCM, OR the other one is to make juggling with push notifications, and send them also and than synchronize what is already sent to the user(bad thing)

Suggestions ?

Comment: IMHO, you can use a service as in your question. Pls see my answer at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573823/how-to-use-signalr-in-android/32574829?s=0|5.7792#32574829 if you have not read it before.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and good, but still it does not answer mine. Service can be killed, so in order to trigger it back the only way I see is to send a push notification.So how you suggest to solve that ?

Comment: If you make it a sticky service (return START_STICKY from onStartCommand), then the service will be recreated after kill with a null intent https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: @DanKuida have you found any solution for this

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran - yes - not to use signlar, sockets and signalR are horrible on mobile, the best solution would be to use commet - as PubNub have implemeented it - but that is quite a lot for a standalone application, so  my solution was to implement a request queue where I trigger all the calls based on type of calls in the queue

Comment: so you are telling that signalR is bad for mobile

Comment: yes thats exatcly what I am telling @M.Yogeshwaran

Comment: then whats your implementation can you please share some ideas regarding this

Comment: The best implementation would be making queries with push notifications/ plus in chat polling in case push fails, buit more advanced would be - message que with retry andd confirmation of delivery, on top of that possible to extend to Jabber/xmpp. a bit mre advanced for large scale would be backend storage with riak and delivery using commet like FB doing that, of course backed with some push for bg response - all depends on the need

Answer (score 1):

BNKs example is good, and to recreate service after kill, just use START_STICKY return value in onStartCommand, as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20557120