# Is there an Android Intent that indicates killing my background services (or main process)?

Tags: android, android-intent, kill-process

Is there an Android Intent that indicates my background services (or main process) were killed? For example, due to low system memory etc.

I would like to have them restarted if they are killed.

Comment: I need this app (rather background service) to restart it.

Comment: Killed background services (with main activity) by system (example due to low system memory, long inactivity (Samsung devices) etc.)

Comment: My own services

Comment: Okay, that makes sense now. Your wording was just odd to start with

Comment: I was under the impression that Android services will restart on their own, so I do not know a solution

Comment: Maybe relevant.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557036/how-to-restart-a-service-after-getting-killed-by-apps-like-advanced-task-killer

Comment: Service restarts yourself only without a violent termination.
I use START_STICKY, but in this case it is not functional

Comment: And the other answers there? AlarmManager?

Comment: You could explain what you have tried so far, in what cases it doesn't work  and add relevant parts of your code to the question.

Comment: Thank you all for the information provided.
I solved the problem by using AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the service again in **onDestroy()** of the service.
Or you can return **START_STICKY** from **onStartCommand()** of the service.