# Finding Longitudes and latitudes when the app is off

Tags: android, google-maps, service

I am new in android.Now i am developing one location based alarm .But in this one i need to take latitudes and longitudes continuously when the user is moving and also the app will be in off mode.I got many codes but all these are working when the app is on.I gave the code below.

### **Service class**

```
public class LocationLoggerService extends Service {
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public MyLocationListener listener;
    public Location previousBestLocation = null;

    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new MyLocationListener();        
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
        // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /** Checks whether two providers are the same */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
          return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
       // handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);     
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("STOP_SERVICE", "DONE");
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);        
    }   

    public static Thread performOnBackgroundThread(final Runnable runnable) {
        final Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.run();
                } finally {

                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
        return t;
    }


    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)
        {
            Log.i("**************************************", "Location changed");
            if(isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
                loc.getLatitude();
                loc.getLongitude();             
                intent.putExtra("Latitude", loc.getLatitude());
                intent.putExtra("Longitude", loc.getLongitude());     
                intent.putExtra("Provider", loc.getProvider());      
                System.out.println("location"+loc.getLatitude());
                sendBroadcast(intent);          
                /*final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());         
                String Text = "";
                try {
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);                
                    Text = "My current location is: "+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); 

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Text = "My current location is: " +"Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() + ", Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();  
                }
                */
                //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Location polled to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }                               
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }


        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }

    }
    }
```

**Activity code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), LocationLoggerService.class.getName());
        ComponentName service = startService(new Intent().setComponent(comp));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add onStartCommand Method in your Service class

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");

     }
     return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

here returned is **Service.START_STICKY**

it will start service even if you kill from recent and app is not running in foreground.

here is more [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9102263/942224) about Service.START_STICKY and START_NON_STICKY