# Precise Semantics of START_STICKY flag for Android Service

Tags: android, android-service

Somehow I am having a hard time parsing the [official description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) of the `START_STICKY` flag:

> Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this
>   service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state
>   but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to
>   re-create the service. Because it is in the started state, it will
>   guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after creating the
>   new service instance; if there are not any pending start commands to
>   be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent
>   object, so you must take care to check for this.
>
> This mode makes sense for things that will be explicitly started and
>   stopped to run for arbitrary periods of time, such as a service
>   performing background music playback.

Specifically, the following four parts do not make technical sense (aka make me go WTF):

- *"if this service's process is killed ..., then leave it in the started state"* [how do you leave something that is killed in the started state?]
- *"Later the system will try to re-create the service. Because it is in the started state, ..."* [why is it in the started state if the system is trying to re-create the service?]
- *"Because it is in the started state, it will guarantee to call onStartCommand(...) ..."* [*"it will guarantee to call"*? sorry, can't parse that phrase linguistically]
- *"This mode makes sense for things that will be explicitly started and stopped to run for arbitrary periods of time, ..."* [*"and stopped to run"*??]

Does anybody have a better spec of this flag? And, to any Googlers reading this: wtf? Can you get it fixed internally pronto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, there are two forms a service can have in Android:

- [*Started service*](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService)
- [*Bound service*](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

The key point to understanding the description is that a *`Started service`* must manage its own lifecycle, i.e. the *ONLY* components that can stop the service is the service itself by calling *`stopSelf()`* or another component by calling *`stopService()`*. Once a *`Started service`* has been started (*`onStartCommand()`* returns) it’s in a started state and it won't stop unless either *`stopSelf()`* or *`stopService()`* is called. So, if the system prematurely kills the service (neither *`stopSelf()`* or *`stopService()`* has been called), the service still is considered to be in a started state. And it’s up to you to tell (signal to) the system how to proceed with the service after killing it by returning a flag in *`onStartCommand()`*.

Probably the description of the `START_STICKY` flag given at the end of [Extending the Service class](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService) will be more clear for you.

P.S. Regarding the *"and stopped to run??"* confusion, try reading it as *"...explicitly started and stopped in order to run..."*

**EDIT:**

Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

[START_STICKY and START_NOT_STICKY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky)

> START_STICKY tells the OS to recreate the service after it has enough memory and call onStartCommand() again with a null intent