# Best way to implement Socket.io in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io, android-lifecycle

I am planning to implement Socket.io in android by [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/) library for a chat based application. As far as I understood the library seems to be pretty good. I want to know how to maintain a **single** socket connection throughout the app all the time?  Here I have listed out ways to achieve, in which I need the best and stable way.

**Three ways**

**MainApplication** Class extends **Application**

By this we have a good scope that the socket connection is maintained in the **main thread**( or application's life cycle) and whenever the socket instance is needed from the activity we can get it easily. But it's main thread which also the problem. It might block the main thread.

**BoundService**

By this way we can **bind** the service with the activities and we can simply use it. Doing in separate thread is the way to achieve IO/Network calls. But cross processing transfer is more expensive than directly accessing in same process.

**Singleton**

Maintaining connection in Singleton also makes sense. But we don't know when the instance is killed by process, because it doesn't work in activity life cycle.

If I makes sense please help me out. If not comment it out.

### Edit

I have given the answer which is more suitable for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Service for Maintaining `socket` connection

As per Ofek Ron mentioned `Service` with `BroadcaseReceiver` is a **better** idea than `BoundService`. Because its a tedious process to maintain communication. And I also recommend `pub/sub` way of broadcasting, like `Otto` or `EventBus` (I myself suggest **Otto** by Square, which is clean and brilliant api).

**Pros of OTTO**
1. Cleaner Api
2. You can subscribe and publish in/to any `Activity`, `Fragment`, `Service` class.
3. **Decoupling**. (You have to couple as less as possible in your code).

And one more point is use **`START_STICKY`** in the  `onStartCommand()` to start service after it is getting destroyed. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky) reference.

### MainApplication to start the service

It's best practice to start the service in the `MainApplication` that extends `Application`. Because the application will be killed when there is a memory constraint or user forcefully closes the app from the stack. So `onStartCommand()` will not be called frequently like if we have implemented in Activity.

### Implementing online status

You can implement online status simply by implementing `Application.LifeCycleCallbacks` in the `MainApplication` class, which has most of the life cycle callbacks of activity and will be notified in the callback. By that you can implement `Online` status simply without any boiler plate codes. (If anyone need help here let me know).

### Uploading or downloading images or files.

Best practice is to implement by `IntentService` because it's running in the a separate thread. I promise which will give the best performance because it is handled by android itself, not like threads created by us.

Comment: simple example of this will be very useful, if you could do that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

First of all, the Application's `onCreate()` is irrelevant in your use case because you can't have a thread running in the background when it was first initiated in a non service code.

Also, I would recommend using [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) instead of creating your own mechanism. It would be best for the device's battery life and much less code for you to handle.

If you do want to implement that chat completely on your own, `Service` is your only choice. You can also combine it with a singleton, but I wouldn't recommend that approach. You can use broadcasts and `BroadcastReceiver` for communicating between your `Service` and `Activity`, I think it is easier than a Bound Service since bounding to the service is asynchronous and it creates a lot of mess compared to simple broadcasting.

Comment: GCM won't work in my case, because I have to maintain `online` and `last seen` status of the user. Broad casting is a far better idea than `BoundService`.

Comment: I still think you can do that with GCM rather than maintainning a live socket, you can open a socket for outgoing only when needed and let GCM handle the incoming. And yeah, broadcasting is better the boundservice in most cases i know.

Comment: Can you please explain why broadcasting is better than boundservice? I tried to google that, but search results are very generic, I will appreciate it if you send me a link on that optic.. thanks

Comment: @simo You should try both and see for yourself. with BoundService you will have to deal with the fact that bounding is async, which is a pain in the ass to handle. in my opinion Broadcasting is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine first way and third way like:

Create `Socket`s in your `Application` and declare them as `static`. So you can maintain and access them every where in you application. Don't forget to create separate `Thread`s to perform the network operations, you can use `ThreadPool` to manage those `Thread`. If you want to update your UI from those `Thread` you can use `Handler` and `Message` to communication with UI `Thread`

Comment: The library itself handling connections and transactions in background so we don't need to implement thread our self. And `Handlers` are pretty old way of communicating. It's better to use `Observables` or `EventBus`. Which is simple and elegant

Answer (score 0):

Before you create your own implementation of a socket.io client, you should give this library a chance: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

I use it in one of my projects to communicate with a node.js server which is working pretty fine. Actually, all of your suggestions are correct and mostly depend on what you want to achieve. However, one context is always available: the application context. Therefore you should keep a singleton instance in the `Application` class and get it by `getApplicationContext()`.

Online status of the user: here you should create a background service which is listening constantly for the users state. As there are not many information, this should be okay and should not drain the battery too much. Additionally you can send a flag if there are new information available and only if there is something new, you start another thread, which is receiving the new data. This keeps the data low.

Chat: the chat data is transfered only when the app is active. So, this should be done in an activity.

Both the service and the activity can access the singleton instance of the socket.io client from the application context. As long as you do not process any complex data on the main thread everything is fine. So, wrap your calls into separate thread and only start them when they are actually needed.

Comment: Actually I am using that library which you mentioned and I had mentioned it too. And listing for the users activities in the background service is a bad idea. Best way is to use `Application.LifeCycleCallbacks` in your Application class.

Comment: In this case, the link in your question is redirecting to the main page of the library. Additionally, I did not say that you should listen for users activities in the background. You should listen for remote changes in background, i.e. when someone goes on/off or sends a new message. This must be done in background, if you want to get notifications when the app is closed.

Comment: Ok sorry for the mistaken.

Comment: See also `ProcessLifecycleOwner` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44461605/2914140.