# Android service destroy after lock screen

Tags: java, android, android-service, wakelock, background-service

I am using `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` in my app to play music. I am also starting service with `startService` method within the service and also using `startForeground` with notification as well as using wakelock require. But still my service is being destroyed after lock.

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            PlaybackService.class));

mService.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

Comment: Look here, you might find something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399123/is-it-possible-to-run-service-in-android-platform-continuously-even-after-lockin

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Context.startForeground()` instead of `Context.startForegroundService()` on Oreo+ devices can cause trouble.
Try to check Build version and call the appropriate method:

For Oreo+: `startForegrountService()`

For lower than Oreo: `startForeground()`