# Is it possible to detect services that will be restarted after getting killed..?

Tags: android, application-restart

I am trying to make a task killer app. I have seen that many of the running services are Automatically restarted after getting killed. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33969065/6697154) post I know that service with `START_STICKY` are automatically restarted. Is it possible to Identify if a service is set for automatic restart or to return `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand`.?