# START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY in Services

Tags: android

What is START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY flag in terms of Android Services. The documentation mentions it

> compatibility version of START_STICKY that does not guarantee that
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) will be called again after being
>   killed.

What is compatibility version? And if its a version of `START_STICKY`, then why is the call to `onStartCommand()` is not guaranteed?And why will anyone use it when it doesn't guarantee that `onStartCommand()` is ever called after the service is killed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [START\_STICKY and START\_NOT\_STICKY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky)

Comment: @piotrek1543 does that duplicate answer all the 3 questions i have asked here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default implementation of [`onStartCommand`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Service.java#508):

```
  public @StartResult int onStartCommand(Intent intent, @StartArgFlags int flags, int startId) {
        onStart(intent, startId);
        return mStartCompatibility ? START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY : START_STICKY;
    }
```

The [`mStartCompatibility`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android11-release/core/java/android/app/Service.java#846) is determined this way:

```
 mStartCompatibility = getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion
                < Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR;
```

In the 1.6 version of the [`Service`](http://androidxref.com/1.6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Service.java#182) there is no implementation of `onStartCommand` only `onStart`.
In the version of 2.1 they made the [`onStart`](http://androidxref.com/2.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Service.java#192) deprecated.
Notice the difference in the parameters, `flags` was introduced there.

By doing this, they will maintain compatibility with older system(PRE Eclair) which expects the old value and they also support the new behaviour in newer systems.