# Countdown timer not run when user close application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, countdowntimer

I had created countdown timer to display timeout it works well when user minimize application but it stops when user close application. i had added code below kindly help me it's an emergency.

this is MainActivity.java

```
public static final String TAG = "Demo";
    TextView t1 ;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
         startService(new Intent(this, count_servie.class));
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {            
            updateGUI(intent);
        }
    };
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();        
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(count_servie.COUNTDOWN_BR));
        }
    private void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);
            t1.setText("Countdown seconds remaining: " +  millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }
```

this is my count_servie.java

```
public class count_servie extends Service {
    public static final String COUNTDOWN_BR = "com.demo.DSemo.countdown_br";
    Intent bi = new Intent(COUNTDOWN_BR);
    CountDownTimer cdt = null;
        public void onCreate() {       
            super.onCreate();
            cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
                    sendBroadcast(bi);
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                }
            };
            cdt.start();
        }
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {   
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {       
            return null;
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you don't know answer don't flag down.

Comment: Anyone have any idea on it please help me.

Comment: please help me i'm not getting proper o/p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `START_STCKY` in your `onStartCommand()` method for the service to run even when app is closed.

```
 ....
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {   
     return START_STCKY;
 } 
 ....
```

You can refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)link for correctly implementing a service.

Alternatively, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky) SO question.

**Update**
Use a `Foreground Service` to avoid your Service being killed. In order to make your service Foreground, replace your `onStartCommand` code with this

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Timer")
            .setContentText("Doing some work...")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

    startForeground(1337, notification);

    cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            bi.putExtra("countdown", millisUntilFinished);
            sendBroadcast(bi);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            stopForeground(true);
        }
    };
    cdt.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**Udpate 2:** Counter using `Service` and `SharedPreferences`

Replace your Actvity's code with this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String SHARED_PREF = "MyPref";
private final static int MAX_COUNTER = 30;

public static final String KEY_COUNTER_SECONDS = "seconds";
public static final String KEY_SAVED_COUNTER = "saved_counter";
public static final String KEY_SAVED_TIME_MILLI = "saved_time_milli";

MyResultReceiver mReceiver;
TextView mTvCounter;
SharedPreferences mSharedPref;
long mMaxCounterValueInSeconds = MAX_COUNTER;
long mCurCounterValue = 0;
boolean mShouldSaveValues;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTvCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_counter);
    mReceiver = new MyResultReceiver(null);
    mSharedPref = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //register listener
    MyService.registerReceiver(mReceiver);

    //get values from shared pref
    long savedCounter = mSharedPref.getLong(KEY_SAVED_COUNTER, -1);
    long savedTime = mSharedPref.getLong(KEY_SAVED_TIME_MILLI, -1);

    //if -1 counter was running when app was closed, get saved values from shared pref
    if (savedTime != -1) {
        //elapsedTime is the time spent in seconds while the app was in background
        long elapsedTime = (getCurrentTimeInMilli() - savedTime)/1000; //convert to sec

        mCurCounterValue = savedCounter + elapsedTime;

        if(mCurCounterValue < MAX_COUNTER){
            //calculate current counter value from values retrieved from shared pref
            mMaxCounterValueInSeconds = MAX_COUNTER - mCurCounterValue;
            //start the value with updated max count value
            startService(mMaxCounterValueInSeconds);
        }else{
            mCurCounterValue = MAX_COUNTER;
        }
    }else{
        //if counter was not running, start the service with max count value = MAX_COUNTER
        startService(mMaxCounterValueInSeconds);
    }

    //update text view
    mTvCounter.setText("" + mCurCounterValue);
}

private void startService(long maxCounter){
    mShouldSaveValues = true;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putLong(KEY_COUNTER_SECONDS, maxCounter);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startService(intent);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop the service
    stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    //unregister listener
    MyService.unregisterReceiver();

    if(mShouldSaveValues) {//save the values only when counter has started
        //save values in the shared preference
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();
        Log.d(TAG, "saving counter: " + Long.parseLong(mTvCounter.getText().toString()));
        editor.putLong(KEY_SAVED_COUNTER, Long.parseLong(mTvCounter.getText().toString()));
        editor.putLong(KEY_SAVED_TIME_MILLI, getCurrentTimeInMilli());
        editor.apply();
    }
}

/**
 * This method returns current time in milli seconds
 *
 * @return time in milliseconds
 */
private long getCurrentTimeInMilli() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    long timeInMilli = date.getTime();
    return timeInMilli;
}

/**
 * ResultReceiver is used to get values from MyService.class
 * It is registered in onResume() &
 * unregistered in onPause()
 */
class MyResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

    public MyResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        String strMilliFinished = resultData.getString(MyService.KEY_MSG);
        updateUI(Long.parseLong(strMilliFinished));
    }

    private void updateUI(final long milliFinished) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mCurCounterValue++;
                mTvCounter.setText("" + mCurCounterValue);

                if(milliFinished == 0) {
                    //resetting counter values

                    mShouldSaveValues = false;
                    mMaxCounterValueInSeconds = MAX_COUNTER;
                    mCurCounterValue = 0;

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putLong(KEY_SAVED_COUNTER, -1);
                    editor.putLong(KEY_SAVED_TIME_MILLI, -1);
                    editor.apply();

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Replace your Service code with this:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service {

public static final String KEY_MSG = "msg";

CountDownTimer cdt = null;
private static ResultReceiver mReceiver;

public MyService() {
}

public static void registerReceiver(ResultReceiver receiver) {
    mReceiver = receiver;
}

public static void unregisterReceiver() {
    mReceiver = null;

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    long maxCounterValueInSeconds = bundle.getLong(MainActivity.KEY_COUNTER_SECONDS);
    long maxCounter = maxCounterValueInSeconds * 1000;
    cdt = new CountDownTimer(maxCounter, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            sendMessage(1, "" + millisUntilFinished);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            sendMessage(1, "" + 0);
            stopSelf();
        }
    };
    cdt.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void sendMessage(int resultCode, String message) {

    if (mReceiver != null) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(KEY_MSG, message);
        mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    cdt.cancel();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
}
```

**Note:** I am using `ResultReceiver` instead of `BroadcastReciver`

Comment: wat do u mean by 'restart application'

Comment: i mean restart timer and i also put code in onStartCommand method

Comment: it working completely but shows notification can you tell me how can i remove it.

Comment: You cannot remove notification of Foreground Service. Its a way of telling users that something is running in the background

Comment: i see at somewhere in which timer is running but not show notification also run in background weather user close application.

Comment: If u dont want to use foreground service then u need to use SharedPreference. Store the couter value when app is being closed and restore it ( by calculating savedCounterValue+ time elapsed) when the app is launched again.

Comment: can you provide a small demo for better understanding

Comment: i really need it please help me

Comment: Thanks bro. i checked it works perfectly now can i make some changes in it ?

Comment: but there is an problem when counter reaches its limit it is not reset like when limit reach at 30 then it is not reset so kindly help me in it

Comment: @ravi_koriya u need to write the logic for that

Comment: sure  i''ll try and success in it. by the way thanks for support nice to deal with you..