# Using Asynctask when the app is killed

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I need to use `AsyncTask` that called "Logout" when my app is killed by swiped. I used `Service` to handle this event but it doesn't work.

Added service tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

My Service code

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    PostClass post = new PostClass();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Started");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        new Logout().execute();
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.e("ClearFromRecentService", "END");
        new Logout().execute();
        stopSelf();
    }

    private class Logout extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        JSONObject j;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        JSONObject jso;
        String veri_string = "";

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.e("MyService", "onPreExecute()");
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        Log.e("MyService", "doInBackground()");
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Log.e("MyService", "onPostExecute()");
    }
    }
    }
```

I started this service in my first activity.

```
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

is there any way to solve this problem ? Thanks..

**Edit:** i changed my `AsyncTask` code. i put some logs after the all lines. When i see my Logcat, "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4" are showing but "test5" and the others are not.

Comment: first of all your service should return `START_STICKY` change this and try your code read this to know the difference 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: You have logged the work flow. did u see logs atleast?

Comment: I can see all logs but the asynctask log is not showing.

Comment: `I can see all logs` So onDestroy() and onTaskRemoved() are both called? Which one?

Comment: Sorry, `onStartCommand` and `onTaskRemoved` logs are showing.

Comment: You have no logs in onPreExcecute() and no log statements in the catch blocks of your task.

Comment: `stopSelf();` And if you put that in onPostExecute() ?

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Well: have you put more log statements now? Which do you see?

Comment: in `onPreExecute()` i can see the log.

Comment: There will be exceptions in doInBackground which you do not catch. (But which are visible in the logcat). Remove all code from doinBackground. Put only a log statement in it. Then you will see that the task runs normally.

Comment: Yes i can see the log. So what can i do ?

Comment: FInd out what goes wrong. Look in the logcat. Add statement one by one and look which one is causing the exception. Pretty normal debugging.

Comment: `veri_string = post.httpPost`  Pretty strange that you use a not local `post ` variable. How do you know its well initialised?

Comment: `PostClass post = new PostClass();`

Comment: You should do that declaration and  call in your asynctask. Move all to the asynctask.

Comment: i don't think so. i added log in `doInBackground()` method as first but it didn't called.

Comment: What do you mean with 'it did not called'? How can it not be 'called' if doInBackground() is called as you stated not long ago. Put a log statement before and after it.

Comment: in `onPreExecute` i'm logging "test" but the same line is not running in `doInBackground`

Comment: Put a log statement before and after it.

Comment: i did it for every single line. Nothing logged.

Comment: Add a catch Exception block to doInBackGround().

Comment: But you said that doInBackground is called. Now is it? Start again with only one log statement.

Comment: Put @Override at those member functions.

Comment: Add a new code block to your post with the modified asynctask.

Comment: @greenapps can you check my updated question ?

Comment: Log.e("test", "test1"); What an ureadable log statement. Why not  Log.e("test", "in onPreExcecute()"); ? And yet better  Log.e(TAG, "in onPreExcecute"); Where you defined final String TAG = "myservice"; in your Service.

Comment: `can you check my updated question ?` NO. You should tell which log statements you see.

Comment: You have no log statemens in the catch blocks.

Comment: You did not put PostClass post = new PostClass(); in the asynctask. This is going to take a long time in this way...

Comment: Sorry, i'm trying.

Comment: it didn't work. Also added log statement to catch block.

Comment: `it didn't work` ? What do you mean? Can you remove all code from onPreExecute, doInbackground and onPostExecute? Then put in every one only one log statement. Tell which log statements you see. I asked you before to do so but until now we do not know the results of this simple test.

Comment: Further i see no log statements in the catch blocks.

Comment: Edited my question. Waiting for the build.

Comment: i saw only `onPreExecute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: 
I test with my phone today, and Use IntentService in other process is working :

```
    <service
        android:name=".LogoutService"
        android:process=":LogoutProcess"/>
    <!-- LogoutService use a different process, So when MyService is destroyed can
         start LogoutService -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

And the two services code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    public static final String TAG = "MyService";
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate() called");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand() called with: intent = [" + intent + "], flags = [" + flags + "], startId = [" + startId + "]");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.e(TAG, "onTaskRemoved() called with: rootIntent = [" + rootIntent + "]");
        Intent logoutService = new Intent(this, LogoutService.class);
        startService(logoutService);
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

LogoutService.java code

```
public class LogoutService extends IntentService {
    public static final String TAG = "LogoutService";
    public LogoutService() {
        super(TAG);
        Log.e(TAG, "LogoutService() called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onHandleIntent() called with: intent = [" + intent + "]");
        // This is in the background thread, just call your logout logic:
        try {
            Log.e(TAG, "onHandleIntent: " );
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://www.google.com").openConnection();
            String result = readInputStreamToString(connection);
            Log.e(TAG, "onHandleIntent() result = [" + result + "]");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "onHandleIntent: 111e" );
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "onHandleIntent: 111a" );
    }
}
```

And the logcat:

```
03-07 10:04:05.969 8146-8146/org.goodev E/MyService: onCreate() called
03-07 10:04:05.969 8146-8146/org.goodev E/MyService: onStartCommand() called with: intent = [Intent { cmp=org.goodev/com.google.samples.gridtopager.MyService }], flags = [0], startId = [1]
03-07 10:04:10.940 8146-8146/org.goodev E/MyService: onTaskRemoved() called with: rootIntent = [Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.goodev/com.google.samples.gridtopager.MainActivity }]
03-07 10:04:10.952 1126-1848/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 8287:org.goodev:LogoutProcess/u0a248 for service org.goodev/com.google.samples.gridtopager.LogoutService
03-07 10:04:11.016 8287-8287/? E/LogoutService: LogoutService() called
03-07 10:04:11.018 8287-8302/? E/LogoutService: onHandleIntent() called with: intent = [Intent { cmp=org.goodev/com.google.samples.gridtopager.LogoutService }]
03-07 10:04:11.018 8287-8302/? E/LogoutService: onHandleIntent: 
03-07 10:04:12.154 8287-8302/org.goodev:LogoutProcess E/LogoutService: onHandleIntent() result = [<!doctype html><html lang="zh-HK"><head><meta content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0" name="viewport"><meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"><meta content="address=no" name="format-detection">...orstr=#3f76d3,GradientType=0)}.gb_8a{display:none!import
03-07 10:04:12.154 8287-8302/org.goodev:LogoutProcess E/LogoutService: onHandleIntent: 111a
```

**WARNING:** Because the LogoutService is running in other process. So in your logcat do not select "Show only selected  application" filter, you should use no filter and filter by tag "MyService|LogoutService".

---

Why not use [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

```
  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    // On your main activity's onDestroy method
    Intent logoutService = new Intent(this, LogoutService.class);
    startService(logoutService);
    super.onDestroy();
  }
```

and

```
public class LogoutService extends IntentService {
    public LogoutService() {
        super("LogoutService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        // This is in the background thread, just call your logout logic:
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            veri_string = post.httpPost(cikisURL, "POST", params, 10000);
            jso = new JSONObject(veri_string);
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("Response: ", veri_string);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you kill your app process, your AsyncTask also be killed. If you want your code execute , you app is running.

Comment: I want to execute my asynctask when app is killed by swiped from recentlist.

Comment: Try this. in your onTaskRemoved method , call `startService(logoutService);
`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    PostClass post = new PostClass();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Started");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        new Logout().execute();
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.e("ClearFromRecentService", "END");
        new Logout().execute();
        stopSelf();
    }

    private class Logout extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        JSONObject j;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        JSONObject jso;
        String veri_string = "";

        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                veri_string = post.httpPost(cikisURL, "POST", params, 10000);
                jso = new JSONObject(veri_string);
            }
            catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("Response: ", veri_string);

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            try {
                if(jso.has("data")) {

                }
                else {

                }
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Try this

Comment: Can you tell what is different here?

Comment: Just  one changes like super.onDestroy() method call in onPostExecute method
and remove  super.onDestroy() method from onDestroy method