# Android background service never stops

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm just learning about the Services in Android .I have not used any stopService() function but I expect my service to stop working as soon as I kill the app(by closing it and removing it from recent screen) .That's not happening and my Log message continues to print.

This is the service class that I'm using

```
class NormalServiceClass : Service() {
    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        thread {
            while (true) {
                Log.d("NORMALSERVICECLASS", "Service working")
                Log.d("NORMALSERVICECLASS", Thread.currentThread().name)
                Thread.sleep(2000)
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

}
```

I'm starting the service in my Activity using

```
startService(Intent(this,NormalServiceClass::class.java))
```

Why is that happening , Since its not a foreground service .

Comment: How do you actually kill an app?

Comment: I close it and remove it from recent screen. I tried the "Terminate application" option from logcat as well .

Comment: `super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)` returns `START_STICKY` which means the system is trying to restart your service, and if your target device is running an Android version below O, the service has a really good chance of recovering.

Answer (score 0):

Do you stop your service?

```
stopService(Intent(this,NormalServiceClass::class.java));
```

Comment: I have edited my question now . Please check

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093271/start-sticky-and-start-not-sticky/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're  adding overhead to your system by making an infinite loop like this:

```kotlin
while (true) {
```

So, solve that **error** first and secondly to stop the service something like this should be enough.

```kotlin
stopSelfResult(startId)
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
```