# Android Service restarting on app exiting and no EXTRA_MESSAGE found anymore

Tags: android, android-intent, service, nullpointerexception, restart

I'm sending a filename (with **EXTRA_MESSAGE**) to a class extending Android **Service**.
I'm receiving in this way:

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { // new start


        mNotificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(getBaseContext());

        if (intent != null)
            meta = intent.getStringArrayExtra(VideoCompress.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        //extracting filename from the whole path
        fileNamePath= meta[0];
```

}

All works fine, except for the fact that when I exit the application (with finish), the Service seems to restart and a null pointer exception is called on:

fileNamePath= meta[0];

because the activities are destroyed, obviously.

Any ideas to solve this ?

Comment: `Stop service` in Activity `onPause()`

Comment: the Activity is not onPause... and I don't want to stop the service, it should continue to work

Comment: But `start service` in `onResume()`

Comment: I'm exiting from the Activity (with a Exit button). So the service stays in background but it is restarted (I don't know why) when I'm completely exiting from the app.

Comment: read the docs when intent can be null in onStartCommand

Comment: the answer from @Autocrab seems to work, many thanks!

Comment: spoken too soon... the background process seems to not continue when exiting from the app...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473957/android-service-restarting-when-application-is-killed this should be the solution

Comment: post more code. show us how you return from `onStartCommand()` and how you manage your background process.