# Running Android App in the Background after "killed"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm developing an Android App for mobile sensor monitoring (accelerometer, gyroscope etc). The application is build on a class that extends from BroadCastReceiver and has communication with a service (a class that extends from Service) which is responsible of recording the sensor data when some android events occurs. When the app is running in the background works nice until I kill the activity (in this activity the user can adjust some params). I want to continue recording after the app is killed, how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: what service did you start service with? I suggest that override onstartcommand with START_STICKY would be helpful

Comment: Service is used to perform long-term background processes and STICKY service ensures to start back again if killed. I think it will provide help as your requirements

Comment: Thanks to you both, with return START_STICKY in the onstartcommand works nice. Also i need to use PowerManager to prevent the Android CPU from going to sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with return START_STICKY (onstartcommand() of the service) and PowerManager inside the service to prevent the Android CPU from going to sleep. Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to add service into your application you need to start service from your activity and then register broadcastreciever with IntentFilters after that your application will never be stop might be you will interested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856767/android-keeping-a-background-service-alive-preventing-process-death)

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of this framework to schedule your service to start at the time that you want. Like on every hour or so

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

but remember that if someone will go to task manager and kill your process there is no possibility to avoid that.

cheers